# BizTalk 2009: Communication with all MessageBoxes has now been re-established

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

have installed BizTalk 2009 on the following environment:

- Windows 2008 server
- SQL Server 2008
- IIS 7
- Visual Studio 2008

I have also installed ESB toolkit 2.0.

The BizTalk applications generally work, except the event log all the time shows this as "information":

"Communication with all MessageBoxes has now been re-established"

No errors appear in the log.

Also when I refresh the ports view in the management console I see they change from "stopped" to "started" and vice versa every few seconds.

Any ideas?

Comment: i see the exact same behavior filling up my logs with these info messages

Answer (score 0):

This is normal.  The Biztalk process goes into hibernation (a less responsive mode) when there is no work to do.  These information messages tell you that a new message has come in and now Biztalk is operating at normal levels.

Answer (score 0):

The error was effectively a [bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980560?wa=wsignin1.0) in Biztalk 2009.

The hotfix was rolled into CU 1, which can be obtained [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2429050).

This issue is also resolved in BizTalk 2010.